# Issue while returning ajax response

Tags: php, laravel, function, multidimensional-array

I want to return a url as ajax response.but before that I'am using an recursive funtion for flattening a multidimensional array keeping key.

```
function response(){
    ...
    $response = Ezpay::PayWithToken($obj);
    $trans_resp = json_decode(json_encode($response),true);
    $resp_array = $this->flatten($trans_resp);
    //saving transaction response from  gateway to sessioion
    Session::push('ezpay_gateway_resp',json_encode($resp_array));
    print_r(Session::get('ezpay_response'))
    return '/gateway/success';
}
```

and recursive function is

```
function flatten($array, $prefix = '') {
      $result = array();
      foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                 $result = $result + $this->flatten($value, $key );
            }
            else {
                 $result[$key] = $value;
            }
      }
      return $result;
}
```

but now the `$result` array is being returned istead of `'/gateway/success'`

Comment: In your response method from where did you obtain `$trans_resp` ?

Comment: $response = Ezpay::PayWithToken($obj);$trans_resp = json_decode(json_encode($response),true);

Comment: In `$this->flatten($trans_resp)` where is `$trans_resp` coming from in `function response()` . I'm sorry If I wasn't clear in my previous comment

Comment: I updated the code please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `print_r(Session::get('ezpay_response'))` from your code,

display the text on the page using echo

```
 echo '/gateway/success';
```

Comment: removed. i just changed the name.but it is not the issue

Comment: what name did you change?

Comment: are you sure you are calling response() and not flatten()?

Comment: i changed the session name and  forgot to change the same in Session::get()

Comment: yeah. only inside response function I'm calling flatten function

Comment: why do you execute a print_r function in your controller?

Comment: so that i can inspect in network tab of browser.it's an ajax response method.It's nothing regarding the print_r.its returning. at function call itself.Is there any mistake in my code

Comment: i see so what's the problem?

Comment: the response function should return the string `'/gateway/success'`

Comment: I'm not getting you.It's returning the same no?

Comment: what is the output of your xhr request now?

Answer (score 0):

You should echo the url:

```
function response(){
    $resp_array = $this->flatten($trans_resp);
    //saving transaction response from  gateway to sessioion
    Session::push('ezpay_gateway_resp',json_encode($resp_array));
    echo '/gateway/success';
}
```

This is a full example.

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
   public function message()
   {
      $msg = "myurl/index";
      return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
   }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('ajax',function()
{
   return view('message');
});
Route::post('/msg','ExampleController@message');
```

Javascript using it:

```
function getMessage(){
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/msg',
       data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
       success:function(data){
          $("#msg").html(data.msg);
       }
    });
}
```